# How to get progress dialog untill get the response from service in android?

Tags: android, web-services, response, show, progress

I am implementing an application with get the response from service and show to view.I have used two text views for get the two types of responses from service.When i click on a text view i am getting response is verry late then the UI is hanging in this time i would like to show busy progress dialog on view and when i got response then i would like to close that progress dialog.i am updating view with response to list view.
I have implemented code as follows:

```
 textView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
waitProgreess = ProgressDialog.show(ShoutGetMsgsScreen.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
 resultFromService = new ParseXml().convertMessages(new Model().getMessages("0"));
lst.setAdapter(new CustomeAdapter(ShoutGetMsgsScreen.this, resultShoutMessage));

    if(resultFromService .size()>5){

                    waitProgreess.dismiss();
                }
   }
        });
```

from the above implementation how can i show a progress dialog and when the view is updated then how can i close progress dialog?

please any body help me...

Comment: Yup use AsncTask or handler to do such things away from your UI thread!

Comment: i don't have more knowledge on use handler or AsncTask.please can u give some sample in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private class GetDATA extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(Activity.this, "", getString("loding..."), true, false);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


resultFromService = new ParseXml().convertMessages(new Model().getMessages("0"));
return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pd != null && pd.isShowing())
            pd.dismiss();
        }

lst.setAdapter(new CustomeAdapter(ShoutGetMsgsScreen.this, resultShoutMessage));

    }
}
```

call like that :-

```
(new GetDATA()).execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Android - AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for this purpose. Just look at some basic tutorial for it. Its have `onPreExecute()` , `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()` for the same needs.

Answer (score 0):

You have two option to do this .

1. Handeler

   Handler has the callBack method i.e. handleMessage() .
2. AsyncTask

   AsyncTask has three callback methods onPreExecute(),doInBackground() and onPostExecute()

You can choose any one of this .

Comment: can u plz provide some sample on use Handler

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link for some to gain some insight into Handlers/AsyncTasks, this also contains some examples: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#concurrency_handler